# Searching for information within grouped data and propogating it to the group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a conundrum.

My data has an ID, a grouping key, a label, and second label. It looks kinda like this

```
|----|----------|-------|------|
|id  |group_col |label1 |label2|
|--- |----------|-------|------|
|1   | 1        | abcd  | 123  |
|2   | 1        | nfrv  | 123  |
|3   | 2        | dfgd  |      |
|4   | 3        | kgff  | 899  |
|5   | 3        | kgff  | 899  |
|6   | 3        | ygoi  |      |
|7   | 4        | tgfo  |      |
|8   | 4        | tgfo  |      |  
|----|----------|-------|------|
```

Now my challenge is to check within every group if two people have the same value for label2 and if so propagate it to all members of the group. And additionally set the same value of label1 for the entire group (preferably the one of the first person) (can also be in a new column if people have an idea).

Expected output should be something like this:

```
|----|----------|-------|------|------------|
|id  |group_col |label1 |label2| label1_new |
|--- |----------|-------|------|------------|
|1   | 1        | abcd  | 123  | abcd       |
|2   | 1        | abcd  | 123  | abcd       |
|3   | 2        | dfgd  |      | dfgd       |
|4   | 3        | kgff  | 899  | kgff       | 
|5   | 3        | kgff  | 899  | kgff       |  
|6   | 3        | ygoi  | 899  | kgff       |  
|7   | 4        | tgfo  |      | tgfo       |  
|8   | 4        | tgfo  |      | tgfo       |  
|----|----------|-------|------|------------|
```

Also mind, this will have to run on millions of rows/groups so should be as efficient as possible

Thanks for your help

Comment: id input 4, 5, 6 do __not__ have matching label2 values. Only id 4 and 5 match. However, in your output your have id 6 with a label1_new value associated with label2 value of 899 which seems to conflict with your business rules.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a bit of a brainwave earlier, and came up with a possible solution. havent tested it on the large data jet, and it is not cleaned up (will do that later).
But if anyone has a better way I would love to hear it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,'abcd',123],
                  [2,1,'nfrv',123],
                  [3,2,'dfgd',''],
                  [4,3,'kgff',899],
                  [5,3,'kgff',899],
                  [6,3,'ygoi',''],
                  [7,4,'tgfo',''],
                  [8,4,'tgfo',''],
                  [9,5,'etre',588],
                    [10,5,'etre',743],
                            [11,5,'dsfe',743]
                           ]),
                  columns=['id','group_col','label1','label2']
                  )

def GroupComparison(df, ID,group_col, label1, label2 ):
    oppdatert=[]
    for group in df.group_col.drop_duplicates():
        g = df.loc[df.group_col == group]
        if g.label2.nunique()<g.id.count():
            npers = g.id.count()
            g = g.reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
            var1 = g.iloc[[0]]['label1']
            var2 = g.iloc[[0]]['label2']
            g['label1']= var1
            g['label2']= var2
            g=g.fillna(method = 'ffill')
            oppdatert.append(g)
    opp = pd.concat(oppdatert)
    return opp

test = GroupComparison(df, 'id', 'group_col', 'label1', 'label2' )
test.head(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

The example added an extra record for group 1, "label2" that interrupted the sequence to illustrate the possibility of the data not being sorted. by label2 values.

## input.csv

```
1,1,abcd,123
1,1,asdf,13
2,1,nfrv,123
3,2,dfgd,
4,3,kgff,899
5,3,kgff,899
6,3,ygoi,899
7,4,tgfo,
8,4,tgfo,
```

````
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
    d["label1_new"] = d["label1"]

    print("```")
    print(d)
    print("```")

    # grouping by group_col and label2 will identify groups to be assigned label1_new values.
    g = d.groupby(by=["group_col", "label2"])
    for key, df_grp in g:
        label1_new = df_grp.iloc[0,2]

        #I didn't understand how to use the Pandas group to update in place.
        #Therefore I made a copy to hold new label1_new values.
        #Then updated the original data frame.
        cp = df_grp.copy()
        cp["label1_new"] = label1_new
        d.update(cp)

    print("```")
    print(d)
    print("```")
````

## Input data frame with label1_new added

The first step was to add the column label1_new with the default value of the original lable1. This
handles all cases where there isn't a label2 group with size > 1.

```
   id  group_col label1  label2 label1_new
0   1          1   abcd   123.0       abcd
1   1          1   asdf    13.0       asdf
2   2          1   nfrv   123.0       nfrv
3   3          2   dfgd     NaN       dfgd
4   4          3   kgff   899.0       kgff
5   5          3   kgff   899.0       kgff
6   6          3   ygoi   899.0       ygoi
7   7          4   tgfo     NaN       tgfo
8   8          4   tgfo     NaN       tgfo
```

## Updated data frame

```
    id  group_col label1  label2 label1_new
0  1.0        1.0   abcd   123.0       abcd
1  1.0        1.0   asdf    13.0       asdf
2  2.0        1.0   nfrv   123.0       abcd
3  3.0        2.0   dfgd     NaN       dfgd
4  4.0        3.0   kgff   899.0       kgff
5  5.0        3.0   kgff   899.0       kgff
6  6.0        3.0   ygoi   899.0       kgff
7  7.0        4.0   tgfo     NaN       tgfo
8  8.0        4.0   tgfo     NaN       tgfo
```

Comment: Looks intresting, I will test it and come back with an answer if it worked here